# Dry up my clothes vs Dry my clothes

Tags: american-english

Is is it **idiomatic** to say:

> **Dry up** your clothes in the dryer after the washer is done spinning.

I know **dry up** means to evaporate, in other words, if you **dry** your clothes **up** you're drying them till they turn into ashes. I've done my research on this sentence already using Google books to see whether I could find this same phrase in books and stuff and guess what? I have. Now I wanna hear from you guys whether this is really usable or not.

https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q="Dry+up+my+clothes"&num=10

Comment: Hello, I was looking at your profile and noticed that you have not selected any answers to your past questions (80 of them) as "accepted". I just wanted to point this out - if any answer helps you, you can accept the answer if you wish to. Here is how [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting answers will motivate others to leave you better answers to your future questions. You don't have to accept answers, but it is generally a good thing to do. :)

Comment: To give some follow-on advice, it's best to wait for a while before accepting an answer. (See [*Not so fast!*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) on meta.) Moreover, you don't always need to accept an answer, but it's usually a good thing to do, and always a good thing to do if at least one of the answers was exceptionally helpful.

Comment: Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not idiomatic to "dry up your clothes" in American English.** To my knowledge, it's also not idiomatic in British English.

You'll notice that of your results, four of the first five results appear to be Indian English. One is a novel self-published by an Indian author, one is a journal review from the Guild of Indian English, one is translated poetry, and one is a transcript of a court case in India.

If it is idiomatic in any form of English, it would be Indian English. I doubt that it's particularly idiomatic there either--check out [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dry%20your%20clothes%2C%20dry%20up%20your%20clothes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdry%20your%20clothes%3B%2Cc0) comparing "dry up your clothes" to "dry your clothes." The first doesn't even register.

Comment: We **dry up** spilled or splashed liquid (usually water). We **dry** things that are wet.